# Py.test skip messages don't show in jenkins

Tags: python, unit-testing, jenkins, pytest

I have a minor issue using py.test for my unit tests.

I use py.test to run my tests and output a junitxml report of the tests.
This xml report is imported in jenkins and generates nice statistics.

When I use a test class which derives from unittest.TestCase, 
I skip expected failures using:

> @unittest.skip("Bug 1234 : This does not work")

This message also shows up in jenkins when selecting this test.

When I don't use a unittest.TestCase class, e.g. to use py.test parametrize functionality,
I skip expected failures using:

> @pytest.mark.xfail(reason="Bug 1234 : This does not work", run=False)

But then this reason is not actually displayed in jenkins, instead it will say:

> Skip Message
>
> expected test failure

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using this line as the first line of the test:

> pytest.skip("Bug 1234: This does not work")

I'd rather have used one of the pytest decorators, but this'll do.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem except I had a different Jenkins message and could not tell which test was skipped.

It turns out that if the only test in the module is a skipped test, then jenkins would not show the test in the test result list (using either decorator or jr-be's soloution).  You could see that there was a skipped test in the total resuls, but could not tell which test or which module the skipped test was in.

To solve this (ok hack solve), I went back to using the decorator on my test and added a dummy test (so have 1 test that runs and 1 test that gets skipped):

```
@pytest.skip('SONIC-3218')
def test_segments_create_delete(self, api):
    logging.info('TestCreateDeleteSegments.test_segments_create_delete')

def test_dummy(self, api):
    '''
    Dummy test to see if suite will display in jenkins if one
    test is run and 1 is skipped (instead of having only skipped tests)
    '''
    logging.info('TestCreateDeleteSegments.test_dummy')
```

For me that works since I would rather have 1 extra dummy test and be able to find my skipped tests.